# Euro symbols JNA conversion issue

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I'm trying to put euro symbol in a Java string that is passed to a native function(using JNA) in this way:

```
/*JAVA*/
String s= new String("Euro symbol=€");

nativefunction(s.getBytes(US-ASCII));


/*C++*/
void nativefunction(char *s)
{
    printf("%s",s);
}
```

native function output: `Euro symbol=?`

Why the symbol is printed as `?` instead `€`.

I also tried to use ascii code of euro symbol(`\0x80`) but the result is the same.

Comment: Have you checked the encoding format of your code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

US-ASCII doesn't contain euro character. Perhaps you meant Windows-1252, if so, use:

```
nativefunction(s.getBytes("Windows-1252"));
```

If it still doesn't work, try to use Unicode escape sequence in Java code:

```
String s= new String("Euro symbol=\u20ac");
```

If it works for `\u20ac` but doesn't work for `€`, you need to configure source code encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, Java encodes strings in UTF-16, which uses two bytes for each character. The UTF codepoint for the EURO SIGN is U+20AC, which is 0x20AC in the UTF-16 encoding. US-ASCII uses one byte for each character. Since the euro sign cannot be represented in US ascii, the encoder replaces this character with a question mark. Read about in in the CharSetEncoder documentation.